# Issue with Symfony's routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm facing a little issue with the routing of Symfony.

This is my controller action:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/pricelist/list/{year}/{week}", name="pricelist_list")
     */
    public function getPricelistAction(Request $request, $year = 0, $week = 0)
    {    
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($year === 0) {
            $year = (int)date('Y');
        }

        if ($week === 0) {
            $week = (int)date('W');
        }

        $start = new \DateTimeImmutable($year . '-1-1');
        $stop = $start->modify('+1 year');

             // ... I return the week and year to my twig
     }
```

Now in my twig I have the following:

```
<div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Year</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="yearSelection">
                {% for y in (year-3)..(year+3) %}
                    <option {% if y == year %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
                            data-url="{{ path('pricelist_list', {'year': y, 'week': week}) }}">
                        {{ y }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Week</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="weekSelection">
                {% for key, w in weeks %}
                    <option {% if w == week %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
                            data-url="{{ url('pricelist_list', {'year': year, 'week': w}) }}">
                        {{ w }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I select a year or a week, it doesn't lead me to the url `admin/pricelist/list/{{year}}/{{week}}` as suggested in my routing, but to: `admin/pricelist/list?year=2015&week=8`.

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong, since other functions on other pages are working correctly with the routing in this way.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is it possible that you have another route with same name that doesn't accept parameters in url and, so, your parameters are converted into query string?

Comment: Hm, I've searched through my project and found several redirects like this: $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pricelist_list')); Could that be the cause?

Comment: No, redirect should not be a problem at all. I'm seeing that you use path() and url(), are you aware of the differences, right?

Comment: I am aware of the differences between those. :)

Comment: Of course if the redirect isn't parametrized, an error will be raised. But if error come with your view, I'm pretty sure this isn't the case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug your routes with: `php app/console router:debug`

Then you will see that *pricelist_list* doesn't accept any parameters.

Possible reasons that popped into my mind:

- You're using the YAML configuration method and your @Route annotations are ignored
- The controller you're editing isn't the one that gets loaded (e.g. a Backup in another folder)

Comment: You are right. I call my pricelists via controller getPricelistAction(), but the actual action which gets the parameters was ofcourse the listAction().